# Question on Aharanov and Ta-Shma (ATS)'s Sparse Hamiltonian Simulation notation

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation

In the equations in section 3.4.2 of Aharonov and Ta-Shma's paper ([pdf](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Eamnon/Papers/AT.stoc03.pdf), [arxiv abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301023)), they define the operator: $$T_1:|k,0\rangle\rightarrow|b_k,m_k,M_k,\tilde{A_k},\tilde{U_k},k\rangle,$$ where $b_k,m_k,M_k,$ and $k$ are all integers and $\tilde{A_k}$ and $\tilde{U_k}$ are $2\times2$ matrices. The state $|b_k\rangle$ can then be taken to be a computational basis state by writing the bit-string representation of $b_k$, and similarly for  $m_k,M_k,$ and $k$.

My question is what is the meaning of $|\tilde{A_k}\rangle$ and $|\tilde{U_k}\rangle$? These are matrices with entries which are not integers, so how are they represented in terms of the computational basis?

Comment: What's wrong with having $\widetilde{A_k},\widetilde{U_k}$ up to a desired level of approximation?  They say they use $\alpha^{O(1)}$ accuracy.

Comment: I understand the approximation, but I don't understand what the state $|\tilde{A_k}\rangle$, for example, is supposed to mean. As in, what would this state be in terms of the computational basis?

Comment: I might have a major misunderstanding but I read these as being row-wise or column-wise unrollings/flattenings of the matrix elements, as in claim 5 of the paper.

Comment: I see. So given a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}A_{00} & A_{01} \\ A_{10} & A_{11} \end{pmatrix}$ the corresponding state would be $A_{00}|00\rangle + A_{01}|01\rangle + A_{10}|10\rangle + A_{11}|11\rangle$? What about normalization? This point is very poorly written about in the paper...

Answer (score 1):

I *think* some of the qubits that are initially part of the $0$ register in $\vert k,0\rangle$ get mapped to (approximations of) the coefficients $A_{min_k,min_k},A_{min_k,max_k},A_{max_k,min_k},A_{max_k,max_k}$, and some others will be mapped to the same for $U_k$.

I think this these coefficients are what the oracles are supposed to return.

I agree this feels like it's written at a very high level of abstraction, but if I understand it correctly, it's not dissimilar to the "[code as data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_as_data)" duality in (classical) computer science.

Comment: This is still not clear to me. So in terms of the computational basis in the $2\times2$ subspace, what is this state: $|A_{\mathrm{min}_k,\mathrm{max}_k}\rangle$? Thanks for the "code as data" link, I will check it out.